# Flutter File_picker package display selected images before uploading

Tags: flutter

I'm making an app where part of it involves a user selecting multiple images and uploading them to firebase storage. For this I'm using file picker package however I'm unable to display the picked images to the user before being uploaded.

So far all tutorials I've seen only show how to return details of picked files(name, size etc) but nothing shows how to display the actual selected images in some sort of a grid view. any help will be appreciated.

The code I'm using to pick files from gallery

```
List<File> files=[];
pickFiles() async {
    try {

      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true,allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],);

      if (result != null) {
        setState(() {
          files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path!)).toList();
        });
      } else {
        // User canceled the picker
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71456791/15950932).

I have created an image picker widget here which you can use to pick images and after you picked the images they are showed in a WRAP widget that is in a grid like view. You just need to add the tag for allowMultipleImage for the image picker function to pick multiple images.

And if you want to have the control over the list of images, meaning to clear the images after upload you can read my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71462897/15950932) solution which is just a modified form of the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert path to FileImage in order to display it in image widget,

```
 final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false);
 if (result == null) return;
 final files = result.files; //EDIT: THIS PROBABLY CAUSED YOU AN ERROR
 String textt = result.files.first.path.toString();
 dynamic placeholder = FileImage(File(textt));
```

Here is complete video to display image picked from file picker to image widget
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oag9VeHfOm4

Github:
https://github.com/MIRTAHAALI/flutter_file_picker/blob/main/main.dart